# Chrome Extension Font Sizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that works perfectly for MOST users, but I am getting reports from some users on windows specifically that the fonts are large and breaking the layout.

I have had them send screen shots and it appears like the extension is zoomed, but it isn't according to them.

Has anyone ever had something like this?

examples -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrHiJ.jpg - What the user is seeing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSIBp.png - What I am seeing, and what it should look like.

Code wise there is nothing special going on, normal myers reset for CSS, I tried enforcing zoom, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Could it be different DPI settings? Or, connected to that, different default zoom levels?

Comment: Xan That's a really good question. That actually may explain it! I am going to give that a shot! I didn't even think about that.

Comment: To be fair, Chrome in High-DPI Windows environment can be quite a pain.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.

Comment: So it's not the DPI. Tried the zoom levels as well, no results. super strange.

Comment: It looks like you may not be setting a "width" value to your containing element. Does explicitly setting a CSS width on a wrapper change anything?

If it doesn't, can you post your popup HTML and popup CSS?

Comment: @StevenPease yep that is being set. It's really a strange bug, it only happens to a very small group of users, but I can't nail down what is common between them other than being on windows.

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS for the popup when you click to "Inspect Popup" (right-click the browser icon). It seems like this could be CSS related, but I'm only able to guess if I can't see it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem..... over 5 years later.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely some of the users have changed the "Page Zoom" setting in chrome://settings/appearance.  Zooming an individual page will not affect the zoom of extensions.  But setting the "Page Zoom" setting does.